# TextBox remove leading and tailing spaces and empty lines better way

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have text box in which user may input some text.
Currently I'm removing all spaces and empty lines using this code:

```
private void RemoveSpacesAndEmptyLines()
{
    textBox.Lines = textBox.Lines.Where(val => val.Trim().Length != 0).ToArray();
    textBox.Lines = textBox.Lines.Select(c => c.Trim()).ToArray();
}
```

But is it possible to do only one call?
I need to have only lines that have something except spaces in it and also remove all spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is it possible to do only one call?

Sure, because you can chain the `Where` and the `Select`:

```
textBox.Lines
    .Where(val => val.Trim().Length != 0)
    .Select(c => c.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I did not think that it could be done this way :) I forgot about chaining. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
textBox.Lines = textBox.Lines
    .Select(l => l.Trim())
    .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function trim (el) {
    el.value = el.value.
       replace (/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/, ""). // removes leading and trailing spaces
       replace (/[ ]{2,}/gi," ").       // replaces multiple spaces with one space 
       replace (/\n +/,"\n");           // Removes spaces after newlines
    return;
}​


onkeypress="return trim(this)"
```